# Getting a NullReferenceException Error when invoking a Select File Dialog Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a real newbie question. I have simple app that selects a picture and display's that picture in a PictureBox.

I decided to mess with the Opacity Attribute so I added a timer and created this cool effect where the Main Form's Opacity is increased by 20% every 400 miliseconds.

The problem is that now when I click the button that invokes the Select File Dialog Box I'm getting a NullReferenceException error.

```
 private void tmrClock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewerForm.ActiveForm.Opacity != 1)
        {
        ActiveForm.Opacity = ActiveForm.Opacity + .20;
        }
    }
```

The error message is pointing to the if statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is ViewerForm and ActiveForm not null ?

Comment: @Obalix: `ViewerForm` is the name of his `Form` class; `ActiveForm` is a `static` property of the base `Form` class, which is `null`.  See my answer.

Comment: @SLaks: It is not in the OP what ViewerForm is, hence, the question.

Comment: @Obalix: I realize that; I answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ActiveForm` property returns the `Form`  object that is currently focused.

When you open a file dialog, there is focused form is not a managed `Form` object, so `ActiveForm` returns `null`.

Assuming that your timer is inside your form, you should simply write `this.Opacity`.  The `this` keyword refers to the `Form` object that the timer is in.

By the way, you should stop your timer when the animation finishes (by calling `tmrClock.Stop()`)

Answer (score 2):

When you show a modal dialog, your form is not active anymore. So `ActiveForm` is the modal dialog, which is not a `Form` (it's a native window), so `ActiveForm` returns null.

Why don't you refer to the Form itself rather than the `ActiveForm` ?

```
private void tmrClock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Opacity != 1)
    {
        this.Opacity = ActiveForm.Opacity + .20;
    }
}
```